# Concise Sentence to describe my workout routine

Tags: sentence-choice

I was in the gym, and someone came to me and asked if we could share the bench. I would've shared, but the thing I am doing two exercises. I do exercise A on the bench, and when I finish the set of exercise A, I do exercise B, and then I switch to A and so on. So, there will be no time for him to share.

How to explain that in a *simple* sentence where he understands why I do not want to share without me looking like a jerk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could say:

> I'd be happy to share, but I'm doing two exercises, and both of them keep me on the bench.

The first part of the sentence - *I'd be happy to share* - lets the other person know you're not trying to be selfish on the bench.

You could also incorporate Laurel's answer into my sentence:

> I'd be happy to share, but I'm **alternating** between two exercises, and both of them keep me on the bench.

Answer (score 1):

You can say you're [alternating](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alternating) between doing exercise A and exercise B. Here's a similar example online:

> Alternate between the two exercises, performing a set of pull-ups, then a set of pushups and then resting before going back to pull-ups. In your first session, perform six sets of three reps on each. In the second session, increase to five sets of five, and in the third session, aim for four sets of eight — [Chron](https://livehealthy.chron.com/pullup-pushup-routine-build-strength-8458.html)